# login_required false negative

Tags: django, session, django-views

I have a weird issue using the `login_required` decorator. I'm using the decorator to restrict access to a view serving files to logged-in users.

When testing with Safari everything works as expected, logged in users can download the file - not logged in users cannot. Whereas testing with Chrome and Firefox gives a false negative, resulting in a login redirect. The redirect happens already in the `login_required` function, the `view` is not entered.

I'm testing with the same user, the user is logged-in both times, and interestingly I only get false negatives with this only file download view.

Running Django on `Debug=True`.

Requested url is:

```
http://localhost:8000/media/accounting/invoices/First-Budget-PO1-AR-2014-007.pdf
```

resulting in a redirect:

```
http://localhost:8000/?next=/media/accounting/invoices/First-Budget-PO1-AR-2014-007.pdf
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^media/(?P<file_path>.*)$', login_required(FileDownloadHandler.as_view()), name='file_download_handler' ),
```

views.py (whereas I think it has no influence as it is not entered)

```
class FileDownloadHandler(View):
    """
    download handler for user uploaded files
    """
    def get(self, request, file_path, **kwargs):
        mimetypes.init()
        #left out details - sanity checks etc for simplicity reasons
        #no redirect happens here.. chrome request do not even enter the view
        fsock = open(file_path,"r")
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        mime_type_guess = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
        if mime_type_guess is not None:
            response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype=mime_type_guess[0])
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_name
        else:
            response = HttpResponseNotFound() 
        return response
```

Would appreciate any hint where I could look at, as it is such a weird issue.

Comment: I'm sure you double checked that you actually logged in using chrome or firefox correct? and cookies are enabled?